# Add margin between cols using Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem applying margin-right to my article.col-sm-8 because if add (for example) 10px to margin-right, my aside.col-sm-4 is placed under the article and I don't want this, I want my aside next to the article.

**My html structure**

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <section class="row">
        <article class="col-sm-8">

        </article>
        <aside class="col-sm-4">

        </aside>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
```

My wrapper has max-width: 1000px;

**Layout without margin-right to article**

[image]

**Layout with margin-right to article**

[image]

**I want this, adding margin-right to article**

[image]

Hope you can help me, Regards!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 uses padding instead of margins to create spacing between columns (the gutter), so if you use a div inside your `aside` div you'll see the gutter.

Since you want it to be `10px` you can set a padding of 5px on both sides of the `article` and `aside`...

http://bootply.com/130020

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but what you will likely want to do is [download a customized version of bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) where you change the @grid-gutter-width.  This will allow you to change the margins for everything.

You could try overriding this css, but my guess is that in all the LESS stuff it is getting used to build out other styles and before you know it, you'll be in wishing you did.

Other than that, I think you will run into a problem with the grid system and using all of the columns and adding margins.  100% + 3% will always end up on the next line.

Another option could be to use padding, that way your width is maintained for the grid system, but you get the visual distance.